# How to select records that have exactly matching column value?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm doing a WPF pet project, suppose I have 2 tables:

```
╔════════════════════╗   ╔══════════════════╗
║ Folders            ║   ║ Tag              ║
╠═══════════╦════════╣   ╠═════════╦════════╣
║ ID        ║ INT    ║   ║ TagID   ║ INT    ║
║ Location  ║ STRING ║   ║ TagName ║ STRING ║
║ Name      ║ STRING ║   ╚═════════╩════════╝
║ TagID     ║ INT    ║
║ Thumbnail ║ STRING ║
╚═══════════╩════════╝
```

And this is what inside them:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════╗   ╔═════════════════╗
║ Folder                                        ║   ║ Tag             ║
╠════╦══════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════════════╣   ╠═══════╦═════════╣
║ ID ║ Location ║ Name  ║ TagID ║ Thumbnail     ║   ║ TagID ║ TagName ║
╠════╬══════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════════════╣   ╠═══════╬═════════╣
║ 1  ║ D:\      ║ Music ║ 1     ║ D:\folder.jpg ║   ║ 1     ║ Heroic  ║
╠════╬══════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════════════╣   ╠═══════╬═════════╣
║ 2  ║ D:\      ║ Music ║ 2     ║ D:\folder.jpg ║   ║ 2     ║ Special ║
╠════╬══════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════════════╣   ╠═══════╬═════════╣
║ 3  ║ E:\      ║ Movie ║ 2     ║ E:\001.jpg    ║   ║ 3     ║ Action  ║
╚════╩══════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════════════╝   ╚═══════╩═════════╝
```

Now I want to select folders that have BOTH 2 tags ("Heroic", "Special").

What I've done is using predicate to select any folder that has "Heroic" or "Special" tag to a temporary table.

Then from that table I group by Location, and select Location where count() == 2 into a list.

And with that list I select from original table where list.Contains(Location).

Are there better/elegant ways to do this? I'm testing with small data sample so everything seems to be okay, but I fear there will be performance issue or hidden bugs when the dataset is large enough.

Comment: It looks like the first 2 folder items are the same except for the tag - are you duplicating records in order to associate 2 different tags? If a Folder may have many tags, the data model should reflect that to avoid repeating data

Comment: Yeah I want each folder has multiple tags. I've made many safeguards inside add / edit tags function to ensure there are no duplicate tags.

Comment: you should think about adding another table to correlate multiple Tags with a given Folder e.g. removing "TagID" from the Folder Table, and creating a "FolderTags" table with a PK column/FolderID/TagID

Comment: Thanks. Will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a FolderTag table to handle many to many relationship, I was able to simplify my query to this:

```
if (tagList != null)
    foreach (string tag in tagList)
        query = query.Where(f => f.Tags.Any(t => t.TagName.ToLower() == tag.ToLower()));
```

This will select any folder that has equal or more than required tags, which is what I truly want but didn't state clearly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, @BlurryShadow!

I think this might help if I understand your question.

Use LINQ to filter your results.  As an example:

```
string tags[] = { "Heroic", "Special" }

//get ids
var tagIds = db.Tag.Where(t => tags.contains(t.TagName)).ToArray();

//related folders
var q = db.Folder.Where(f => tagIds.contains(f.TagId)).ToList();
```

`q` would then contain only records from your table where `Tag.TagName` is either "Heroic" or "Special"

or if you have entity relationships configured:

`var q = db.Folder.Where(f => tags.contains(f.Tag.TagName)).ToList();`

Comment: Sorry but I need to return records that have both "Heroic" and "Special" tags.

Comment: thanks for the clarification!  See @Saggio comment beneath your question above regarding creating another table to handle the one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Good suggestion, I definitely will do that. But that still does not help simplify my query.